# How to write a mixin in SCSS for having two dynamic variables in the class name

Tags: css, sass

How can I write a mixin in SCSS with a class names that has two dynamic variables. For example, the class names can be 4 different types
1. .tooltip
2. .tooltip_left
3. .tooltip_wizard
4. .tooltip_left_wizard

so the .tooltip will always remain same but the next conditions of having a specific direction (left, right, bottom, top) and color (wizard, warning, danger, success, deactivated).

I am not able to get the mixin to work for .tooltip_left_wizard. How can I achieve this?

Here is a code I have written for the top and bottom directions.

```
@each $direction, $color in 'left' 'right' 'bottom' 'top' {
.tooltip_#{$direction}_#{$color} {
    /* Base styles for the entire tooltip */
    &:before,
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      transition:         
        opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
        visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
        transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
      transform:         translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      pointer-events: none;
    } 
    /* Show the entire tooltip on hover and focus */
    &:hover:before,
    &:hover:after,
    &:focus:before,
    &:focus:after {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Base styles for the tooltip's directional arrow */
    &:before{
      z-index: 1001;
      border: 6px solid transparent;
      background: transparent;
      content: "";
    }

    /* Base styles for the tooltip's content area */
    &:after{
      z-index: 1000;
      padding: 8px;
      width: 160px;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      content: attr(data-tooltip);
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }   
    @if $direction == "top"{
      /* Top (default) */
      .tooltip:before,
      .tooltip:after,
      .tooltip_top:before,
      .tooltip_top:after,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:before,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:after {
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 50%;
      }

      .tooltip:before,
      .tooltip_top:before,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:before {
        margin-left: -6px;
        margin-bottom: -12px;
        @if $color == "wizard"{
          border-top-color: $accentBlue; 
        }
        @else if $color == "success"{
          border-top-color: $accentGreen; 
        }
        @else if $color == "warning"{
          border-top-color: $accentYellow; 
        }
        @else if $color == "danger"{
          border-top-color: $accentOrange; 
        }
        @else if $color == "deactivated"{
          border-top-color: $gray45; 
        }
        @else {
          border-top-color: $gray90;
        }
      }

      /* Horizontally align top/bottom tooltips */
      .tooltip:after,
      .tooltip_top:after,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:after {
        margin-left: -80px;
      }

      .tooltip:hover:before,
      .tooltip:hover:after,
      .tooltip:focus:before,
      .tooltip:focus:after,
      .tooltip_top:hover:before,
      .tooltip_top:hover:after,
      .tooltip_top:focus:before,
      .tooltip_top:focus:after,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:hover:before,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:hover:after,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:focus:before,
      .tooltip_top_#{$color}:focus:after {
        transform: translateY(-12px); 
      }
    }//end of top

    @else if $direction == "bottom"{
      .tooltip_bottom:before,  
      .tooltip_bottom:after,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:before,  
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:after {
        top: 100%;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 50%;
      }

      .tooltip_bottom:before,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:before {
        margin-top: -12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        @if $color == "wizard"{
          border-top-color: $accentBlue; 
        }
        @else if $color == "success"{
          border-top-color: $accentGreen; 
        }
        @else if $color == "warning"{
          border-top-color: $accentYellow; 
        }
        @else if $color == "danger"{
          border-top-color: $accentOrange; 
        }
        @else if $color == "deactivated"{
          border-top-color: $gray45; 
        }
        @else {
          border-top-color: $gray90;
        }
      }

      .tooltip_bottom:hover:before,
      .tooltip_bottom:hover:after,
      .tooltip_bottom:focus:before,
      .tooltip_bottom:focus:after,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:hover:before,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:hover:after,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:focus:before,
      .tooltip_bottom_#{$color}:focus:after {
        transform:         translateY(12px); 
      }
    }

  }//end of tooltip class
}//end of mixin
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand exactly what you're looking for if you provide a **minimal** example instead of all these unnecessary styles. Also an example of the output would be nice.

Comment: The class declaration is going to be like this <a href="#" class="tooltip_left_wizard" data-tooltip="This is a left aligned tooltip">Tooltip Left</a> The class name takes in two things one is the direction and othe is the color. How can I write the mixin like .tooltip_#{$direction}_#{$color} {} where the $direction and the $color are dynamic variables. As you see in the above code only $direction is being accepted but the $color is not. I wanted to know how to get the syntax for .tooltip_direction_color.

Comment: Of course it's not getting accepted, you're not looping over it: `@each $direction, $color in 'left' 'right' 'bottom' 'top'`. You never specified values for `color`.

Comment: Can you show me how I can do that?

Comment: Why not create these styles individually and apply them in the html? A class name shouldn't describe what the style does/looks like but rather what it's used for.  What if later on you want all the `.tooltip_top_wizard` styles to be in a different position like `center`? You'll have to update the HTML everywhere it's used.